# How to reliably keep a list of servers in a company network

Tags: ip, virtual-network, autodiscovery

We want to set up a connection to several servers at a customer site and are requested to deal with potentially changing IP addresses as they don't want to keep track of the MAC addresses used, with some quick research I came up with the following options:

- Broadcast: Using some discovery mechanism like mDNS whereas UDP broadcasts would have to be routed to all relevant subnets
- Centralized: Having one Dynamic DNS server with a static IP which all servers register to and is known (could also be via some provider over the internet, but undesirable)
- Hybrid: Having one bootstrap node to establish a virtual network (e.g. [meshbird](https://github.com/meshbird/meshbird)) and then use some discovery mechanism
- (highly undesirable) Doing a "bruteforce" IP range lookup and then checking if relevant ports are open

Are there any other options I am not aware of? If broadcasting doesn't work, which method would be the quickest and most reliable to have a simple "Identifier -> IP" mapping in a local network without access to the router?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: You are not helping me nor the community without giving reasons or hints on what to improve.

Answer (score 2):

DNS. Every network should have name services, sometimes bundled or integrated as DNS, DHCP, and IPAM (DDI).

Comment: As I understand it, this doesn't really answer my question as you need to keep track of the mac addresses for the DHCP server to keep track of the servers? That's why I mentioned alternative approaches with for example DDNS. If the question is unclear, I would appreciate help to formulate it better :-)

Comment: Not necessarily. Names can come from the DHCP host option, ask a DDI vendor. Or perhaps they are already using an automatically updated DNS, such as AD DS integrated. If they have no DNS and no static addressing, I don't know how their servers are discoverable.